# Are there other ways to route packets once received?

Tags: routes, network-programming, packet, online-game

So I'm working on the networking system for a project of mine (A game, if such information is relevant.) I'm using tcpip v6 and I've decided on basically having the packet's format be

```
2 bytes: Packet ID  
2 bytes: Packet Length  
n bytes: Payload
```

I figure having the option of 65k different packets gives me plenty of wiggle room, and I can't imagine a packet ever getting bigger than that (In a game, that'd be a smidge silly.)

Currently, I have an unordered map that maps an int to a function object:

```
std::unordered_map<unsigned int, std::function<void(char*, unsigned int)>> Map =
{
    {PID_NULL, PacketGetNull},
    {PID_USER_INFO, PacketGetUserInfo},
    {PID_LOGIN_FAILED, PacketLoginFailed},
    {PID_PRESENT_CHAR_LIST, PacketPresentCharList},
    {PID_PRESENT_WORLD_LIST, PacketPresentWorldList},
    {PID_CHAT, PacketChat},
    {PID_ADD_FRIEND, PacketAddFriend},
    {PID_REMOVE_FRIEND, PacketRemoveFriend},
    //...
};
```

And when processing the packet, I basically do something like this:

```
unsigned short PacketID = 0;
unsigned short PacketLen = 0;
PACKET_READ(Packet, unsigned short, Pos, PacketID);
PACKET_READ(Packet, unsigned short, Pos, PacketLen);

auto Iter = Map.find(PacketID);
if (Iter != Map.end())
    Iter->second(Packet, PacketLen);
else
    printf("Error, packet type not found!\n");
```

Yeah, it's a bit light on the error checking. This is just example code to demonstrate.

But yeah, are there other ways to route packets depending on their ID? Even if they're not *technically* better, even knowing of alternatives would be neat, if only for educational purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to use an array/vector of functions to avoid the (inexpensive?) call to **find** but the design is similar to what you're already doing (C code):

```
enum PacketID {
   PID_NULL = 0,
   PID_USER_INFO = 1,
   /* ... */
   PID_NUM_OF_IDS
};

void (*pkt_handler[])(char *, unsigned int) = {
    PacketGetNull,
    PacketGetUserInfo,
    /* ... */
};

void HandlePacket(enum PacketID pkt_id, char *pkt, unsigned int pkt_len)
{
    if (pkt_id >= PID_NUM_OF_IDS) {
        printf("Error, packet type not found!\n");
        return;
    }

    pkt_handler[pkt_id](pkt, pkt_len);
}
```

Comment: Very similar yeah. Since I'm using an unordered map, supposedly the lookup time is going to be constant so I can't imagine it'd have that much of an effect. I'm mostly sticking to the map instead for flexability reasons. For some reason I completely forgot about checking the packet ID for valid numbers though, feel like an idiot for that. Thanks :D